# Statistics quantitative

Tags: statistics, quantitative

1% of customers are interested in a vertical for snow removal. We run a survey on the
customers that tells with 99% accuracy whether the customer is interested in this vertical. All
customers answer the survey.

If the survey indicates that the customer is interested what is the probability that the
customer wants the vertical?

Comment: hey guys i will need to solve this problem will you have some tips to help me to resolve this small problem??

Comment: Welcome to SO. I don't think you will get an answer here, because it has nothing to do with programming. Try one of the other networks, such as stats.stackexchange.com. Also, I think the question could benefit from some more information. I am not really sure what it is that you are asking for. Try being more precise in your groups. For example, you are talking about customers, survey participants, people interested in a vertical (what is that actually?). Good luck